# How to Reduce AIR app file size?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, mobile, air, embed

I've uploaded an AIR-built .ipa file to Apple. From Apple: "The app binary listed below was 8 MB when you submitted it, but will be 20 MB once processed for the App Store"

So I'm trying to trim it.  I've gotten rid of all unused .as classes and all unused assets. Does anyone have any clever way of reducing file size further? One way I thought of is this:

If in class A I have:

```
[Embed(source="assets/newButtons/purple/purpleHomeSmall.png")]
```

and then I re-embed it in class B with the same code, does that mean it is embedded twice with twice the file size? If so, how would I embed it in one class but have access to it in other classes?

Edit: I've discovered that if you have assets in your project that you don't use, the compiler STILL ADDS them. So you have to get rid of them before making a release build.

Comment: Check the resulting IPA-file (it actually is a ZIP-file - so you may rename and extract it). Does it contain the files you expect or maybe are they actually embedded twice?

Comment: I renamed and unzipped. It created a folder called Payload, inside of which is 1 item, an .app file, with a size of 22 meg. (I'm on Mac).

Comment: Now use show bundle content on your mac when selecting that app.

Comment: Cool trick - thanks! I only see the files once, but those are the .png source files. The Unix executable file is 21 meg; I can't tell whether they're in there twice or not.

Comment: basically using same resource twice should be detected by the flex compiler, and user swf size should not be doubled in this case.

Comment: 21megs is rather big for the executable itself. But then again, I guess that is the price you pay for using a non native solution demanding a special runtime environment / cross compiled code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of embedding images in each source file, what I do is create a class in the default package, where I place all my images as static public variables. Something like this:

```
package {
  public class Icons{
    [Embed(source="assets/icon1.png")] [Bindable] static public var icon1:Class;
  }
}
```

Whenever I need the icon, I just use `Icons.icon1`.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct because it's such an excellent idea and will help with keeping assets organized and modular.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of embedding the source why not just load it from URI at runtime? 
Create an abstract bitmap class that builds a bitmap from the URI and places it on stage. 
This way you can ensure the bitmap is only stored once and is loaded lazily.

**Update**

you can add a folder in the air for iOS settings dialog. 
Place the images you want and then:

```
var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var theURL:String = "string to your uri can be local or web";
var imageRequest = new URLRequest(theURL);

imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

imageLoader.load(imageRequest);

function onComplete(evt:Event)
{

addChild(imageLoader.content);

}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. But I imagine the size of the .png file would have to be included in the app, if it's local to the device (I don't want the app to go out to the internet to find an asset every time it loads). Hmmm... Can you post sample code? Meanwhile I've made a couple of discoveries that I've added as an Edit, above. Thanks!

Comment: @davidbates, this is valid only for flex web apps, where embedded resources are included inside the swf at compile time. When you have an air app, the whole content of the files which are not included inside the swf and are marked to be published will be included inside the resulted  .air / .ipa file

Comment: Thanks Adrian, that's what I suspected.

Comment: Adrian, while they are included inside the .ipa file they will only be included once. (which was what the original question was about) Then you can reference them in as needed knowing your swf will not have multiples of these embedded. They are still semi-embedded in this case since they are packaged with the .ipa.

Comment: @davidbates, thanks. But I have determined that the assets will only be included once even if the embeds are repeated in different classes.

Answer (score 1):

One option i have used is to compile the ipa with only the most necessary assets and then when the user first initializes the app have it download and store further assets in the application storage (this could be done with a single zip-file and the FZip class: http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/)

This way the app only has to download the assets once (on first run) and they are immediately available in the future from the local system.

Comment: Do you know what the implications of this are for initial file size when you upload the app? Because that is what Apple and android markets are calculating. Also have you tested to see if this would work on both platforms? Thanks.

Comment: The implication must be that the initial file size is smaller - because i have used this setup to that exact purpose. Also - this definitely works in iOS and i see no reason why it should not work in Android as well.

Comment: I think this is a good idea but we need test data. I'll try to do a test if you haven't. If you have, please provide info on the asset file size(s) before and after compression, and the size of the resulting .ipa. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ! Your app will be more than 20Mb and its like that. Because the need of Adobe AIR runtime, embedded in your IPA.

So its useless to try to optimize your code, asset .... should chase adobe for this job !

My application: prestadget is 800Ko as APK (w/o AIR runtime) but 21Mo as IPA ;-( same code

Comment: This is not correct. My app came in at 19.8 meg, just enough to squeak under the wireless network limit.

Comment: It's called Apology Wiz. You can see what it does on the app store -- tilting left or right changes meaning; shake to rewrite; send via text or email.